# Форматирование химических реакций на php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть текстовые химические реакции, выбираемые из базы, типа такой:

Ce2(SO4)3 + (NH4)2S2O8 = 2Ce(SO4)2 + (NH4)2SO4

Нужно все числа (в том числе встречаются числа с запятой) сделать подстрочными (добавить html-теги `<sub>`), кроме чисел в начале строки и после пробелов.

Попробовал сделать посимвольным перебором, но получается как-то сложно. Мне подсказали, что вроде как можно упростить или использованием массива или через регулярные выражения (`preg_match`). Регулярными выражениями нашел, как сделать все числа подстрочными, но ограничить выборку у меня не получается.

Как правильно и рационально обработать такую строку?

Comment: `(?<!^)(?<! )\d+(,\d+)*`   -  https://regex101.com/r/6z3gGp/1

Comment: еще может 1-x встретиться :)

Comment: @splash58 Я бы еще смотрел кроме "не пробелов" "не плюсы и равно". На случай если без пробелов запишут строку

Comment: можно, наверное, если не опускаю чего, брать после букв или скобки `(?<=[A-Za-z)])\d+(,\d+)*`

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли! Да, мне нужно получить html-код.

Comment: В итоге получилась такая строка:    $formula = preg_replace("/(?<!^)(?<! )\d+(,\d+)*/","<sub>$0</sub>", $formula);

Comment: @ruslan2021 оформите самоответом

Comment: А можно еще сделать, чтоб после квадратных скобок тоже числа становились подстрочными?

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, splash58!
В итоге получилась такая строка:

```
$formula = preg_replace("/(?<=[A-Za-z)\]])\d+(,\d+)*/","<sub>$0</sub>", $formula)
```

которая делает строку html с числами в виде подстрочных индексов.
Второй, предложенный вами вариант, не берет двухзначные числа.

Comment: Кто минусует, добавляйте, пожалуйста, пояснение комментарием. Интересно, какие недостатки вы видите.